# Efficency of Actions

Tags: smart-contract, cpu

I am new to smart contracts, and I am developing a smart contract for a game.
I am trying to understand if the smart contract that I created is efficient or not.

I have deployed the smart contract on the testnet. Then, I made some transactions and I saw that the CPU usage change, it is not the same even if I call the same action.

There is a way to know how much CPU an action will consume(approximately)?

If an action of a smart contract use around 1ms of CPU in the test net, in the mainnet the usage of CPU will be similar?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far there is no easy way to reliably measure CPU-usage of actions as there are many factors playing into this but testnet-cpu-usage is most of the time a good benchmark anyways.

I'd recommend you to use multiple testnets to measure cpu-usage while calculating avg-cpu-usage.

Mandel v3.1.0-rc1 now also contains a "Transaction Resource Cost Estimation"-endpoint and it's very likely upcoming versions will contain this endpoint while Node-Operators on both testnets (few nodes on testnets are already running Madnel V3.1.0-rc1) and mainnets will host it ([take a look here](https://github.com/eosnetworkfoundation/mandel/releases/tag/v3.1.0-rc1))

Often the diverse mainnets are a bit faster in processing than the testnets but it's not certain that they are while multiple other factors play into this. ([take a look here](https://www.alohaeos.com/tools/benchmarks))

When your smart contract gets closer to a production state you can also just test on a mainnet.